# LINQ statement to write to a list if item is unique

Tags: linq

I have a list of strings called 'Categories', and a single string called 'category'.  Using LINQ, how would I add 'category' to 'Categories' only if 'category' doesn't already exist in the list?

Comment: Linq is for _querying_, not _updating_.  You could write a linq query that obtains the members to add, but you'll still need to add them to the original list separately.

Comment: I see, so then I can use an if statement to check if the category is unique

Comment: As an aside, if you want a collection that doesn't allow duplicates you could use a `HashSet<string>` instead. Then you don't even need to check if it is already contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Linq at all:

```
if(!categories.Contains(category))
    categories.Add(category);
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is for querying data. You don't need LINQ. Also if you are only interested in distinct items then use [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
HashSet<string> categories = new HashSet<string>();
categories.Add("category");
```

See: [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A HashSet collection is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate
>   elements. If order or element duplication is more important than
>   performance for your application, consider using the List class
>   together with the Sort method.

If order of the element is important then you can use `List<T>` with a check, like:

```
List<string> categories = new List<string>();
if(!categories.Contains("category"))
{  
    categories.Add("category");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you really need a list? (specifically, index access?)

If you just need a collection of unique items which you can iterate through, you'd probably be better off with a HashSet.  Then it would just be:

```
categories.Add(category);    // return 'false' if category already present.
```